# Finding value of f statistic to test for difference between treatment means given the following table

Tags: f-test

[image]

Im not really good with statistics and cant really find a way to answer this question.

Finding value of f statistic to test for difference between treatment means given the following table.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to have a look at a *One-Way Anova Table*. Then calculate the necessary quantities to find the F-value. Then look up the p-value.

[image: a busy cat]

Source: https://controls.engin.umich.edu/wiki/index.php/Design_of_experiments_via_taguchi_methods:_one_and_two_way_layouts